# loading constraint violation in Websphere

Tags: websphere, classloader

We are building a webapp with Websphere 7 as target environment, it connects to webservices using CXF. We have done our tests locally using Jetty and everything went fine. We are now trying to deploy the application in Websphere and I get anLinkageError that I really don't understand the meaning of this error ...

```
    [11/01/12 10:25:45:716 CET] 00000013 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[loading constraint violation: loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@fb40fb4" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext" defined by loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@6ba26ba2"]: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@fb40fb4" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext" defined by loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@6ba26ba2"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:773)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:688)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:529)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createDefaultDataBinding(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.getDataBinding(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:105)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.generatedWrapperBeanClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:654)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:630)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:394)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:505)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:241)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:202)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:153)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:151)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:465)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:332)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:319)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:103)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.getPortStub(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:413)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.prepare(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:337)
at org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxWsPortClientInterceptor.java:478)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy365.logAccessToApplicationForUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:416)
at org.apache.wicket.proxy.$Proxy397.logAccessToApplicationForUser(Unknown Source)
at com.bnpp.ecom.emm.EMMHomePage.onInitialize(EMMHomePage.java:52)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.fireInitialize(Component.java:920)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.internalInitialize(MarkupContainer.java:1002)
at org.apache.wicket.Page.internalPrepareForRender(Page.java:278)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2271)
at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:1035)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:105)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:224)
at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:167)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:750)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:252)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:209)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:280)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:162)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:218)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1062)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:759)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Does this mean anything to one of you ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is effectively the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861807/was-6-1-java-lang-verifyerror-class-loading-constraint-violated).  In your case, your application is including the javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext API, and you're referencing some class outside your application that has a dependency on the same class defined by the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
+    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Seems to problem was / is caused by jaxb-api classes which conflicts with the WebSphere classes.