# Uncaught exception thrown while accessing data from db2 using type 4 driver

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, db2, classloader

I get an uncaught exception error while I try to fetch the data from db2 using type 4 driver within the servlet.I used db2jcc.jar and its license file **it works first time** but after some time it shows following exception

> Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: Check. 
>   Exception thrown : java.lang.VerifyError: class loading constraint violated (class: com/ibm/db2/jcc/am/jb method: a(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/SQLJSection;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/hb;Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/hb;)Lcom/ibm/db2/jcc/am/um;) at pc: 0

Please help me to resolve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Could be broken jar file, or wrong license or could be that that class already loaded from some other place check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861807/was-6-1-java-lang-verifyerror-class-loading-constraint-violated

Comment: Show us the code that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.VerifyError: occurs when your classloader finds two copies of same class. I suspect two jars are visible for your classloader. Make sure only required jars are there.

Comment: please tell me the procedure to remove copy of jars..??

Comment: Check your lib and classpath locations that same jar exists twice (or) multiple versions of same jar.