# JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated

Tags: java, web-services, struts2, websphere

Hi i am new to the web services please help out as i was facing this problem actually my code is running fine in tomcat but when i deployed this project in the web services i am facing the problem . i have kept the class loading parent_last and tried and i if place parent first i am getting in compatible error at WSBindingProvider and for parent_last i am getting the following exception

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/message   /jaxb/AttachmentMarshallerImpl, method=addMtomAttachment(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, pc=0
Stacktraces
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1062)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:982)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3944)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

i am thinking that the error is at ress.loadReport(reportPath,historyID); every thing is fine in tomcat but i am not getting why this happens in web shepere 
thank you in advance i am using the bello jars

```
  activation-1.1.jar
  antlr-2.7.2.jar
  apache-jakarta-commons-discovery.jar
  asm-3.3.jar
  commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
  commons-chain-1.2.jar
  commons-collections-3.1.jar
  commons-digester-2.0.jar
  commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
  commons-io-2.0.1.jar
  commons-lang3-3.1.jar
  commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
  commons-logging-1.2.1.1.jar
  commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
  commons-pool-1.5.4-sources.jar
  freemarker-2.3.19.jar
  gmbal-api-only.jar
  gson.jar
  javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
  jaxb-impl-2.2.6.jar
  jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar
  jaxws-rt.jar
  log4j.jar
  ognl-3.0.5.jar
  policy-2.2.1.jar
  stax-ex-1.2.jar
  streambuffer.jar
  struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-dwr-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-embeddedjsp-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-javatemplates-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-jquery-chart-plugin-3.3.3.jar
  struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.3.3.jar
  struts2-jquery-plugin-3.3.3.jar
  struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin-3.3.3.jar
  struts2-jquery-tree-plugin-3.3.3.jar
  struts2-jsf-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
  tiles-api-2.0.6.jar
  tiles-core-2.0.6.jar
  tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar
  xwork-core-2.3.4.1.jar
```

I am using web services Soap in my application

Comment: Are you using PARENT_LAST class loader delegation?  If so, why?  What happens if you try PARENT_FIRST?  I suspect the issue is that you've included activation.jar in your WAR; WebSphere includes its own copy of those classes, but Tomcat does not.  Linkage errors are notoriously extremely difficult to diagnose, so I don't have a thorough explanation for why that JAR is causing the problem, but I would try removing it.

Comment: Thank you , i got the result by removing activation.jar can you please explain the reason please  and thank you once again for your fast reply which helped me a lot .

Comment: There isn't sufficient information in the stack trace to give a full explanation (presumably there is a "Caused by" that you didn't include?).  Even if there is a full stack trace, I probably won't be able to give a complete explanation because the JVM doesn't really give sufficient information.  Here's a previous answer I gave that gives more details on these kinds of errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861807/was-6-1-java-lang-verifyerror-class-loading-constraint-violated

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error. started working fie after remove the activation.jar